# ggplot2: barplot of fractions of single level of the factor in each bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, stacked

For example we have usual stacked bar plot:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=color, fill=cut))+geom_bar(position="fill")
```

[image]

And I want to make same plot but leave on it only one of "Cut" - types. For example "Ideal" (purple one). Thus, it should be something like histogram of fraction of the Ideal diamonds among all other diamonds having same color. Can I do this within ggplot?

Answer (score 5):

If you pre-summarize the data, it is straightforward:

```
library("plyr")

idl <- ddply(diamonds, .(color), summarize, 
             idealpct = sum(cut=="Ideal")/length(cut))

ggplot(idl, aes(x=color, y=idealpct)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course. Thabk you very much. I just wondered, maybe it is implemented in ggplot2.I thought that this is a very common thing to do